# Mysql e python erro ao inserir dados

Tags: mysql, python, banco-de-dados

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#encoding: utf-8
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="[--CENSURADO--]",
  passwd="[--CENSURADO--]",
  database="Planilhas"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

clientes = []

print "Loading table..."
f = open("Completo.csv", "r")
for x in f:  
  clientes.append(x)

temp = []
for x in clientes:
        temp.append(x.split(';'))
clientes = temp

for c in clientes:
        sql = """INSERT INTO 'Completa'('id', 'cpf', 'nome', 'ordem', 'tipo', 'posto', 'sub on', 'upag', 'valor$
"""
        values = ()
        for data in c:
                sql = sql.replace("%s", data, 1)

        print sql
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        mydb.commit()
```

Ele basicamente, lê um arquivo .csv com 25 colunas e pega os dados em cada linha e substitui na query na referência %s e teoricamente a insere no banco, mas retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_for_completa.py", line 33, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 559, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 494, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 396, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Completa'('id', 'cpf', 'nome', 'ordem', 'tipo', 'posto', 'sub on', 'upag', 'val' at line 1
```

Saída do código:

```
Loading table... INSERT INTO 'Completa'('id', 'cpf', 'nome', 'ordem', 'tipo', 'posto', 'sub on', 'upag', 'valor', 'prazo', 'banco', 'nascimento', 'endereco', 'numero', 'complemento', 'bairro', 'cidade', 'uf', 'cep', 'tel_fixo_1', 'tel_fixo_2', 'tel_fixo_3', 'tel_cel_1', 'tel_cel_2', 'tel_cel_3') VALUES ('','CPF','NOME','ORDEM','TIPO','POSTO','SUB_OM','UPAG','VALOR','PRAZO','BANCO','Data Nasc','ENDERECO','NUMERO','COMPLEMENTO','BAIRRO','CIDADE','UF','CEP','FIXO1_TEL','FIXO2_TEL','FIXO3_TEL','CEL1_TEL','CEL2_TEL','CEL3_TEL ')
```

Comment: sql = """INSERT INTO Completa('id', 'cpf', 'nome', 'ordem', 'tipo', 'posto', 'sub on', 'upag', 'valor', 'prazo', 'banco', 'nascimento', 'endereco', 'numero', 'complemento', 'bairro', 'cidade', 'uf', 'cep', 'tel_fixo_1', 'tel_fixo_2', 'tel_fixo_3', 'tel_cel_1', 'tel_cel_2', 'tel_cel_3') VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') """

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma dica, para ler arquivos `csv` use o módulo `csv`, ao invés de dividir os dados você mesmo, é bem mais fácil.

Agora, respondendo a sua pergunta para inserir dados no mysql usando o mysql connector, você **não deve substituir** o %s pelo valor - ao invés disso, passe os valores separadamente para o método `.execute()`, e o mysql cuidará de inserí-los corretamente na query.

```
import csv

sql = """INSERT INTO Completa(id, cpf, nome, ordem, tipo, posto, `sub on`, upag, valor, prazo, banco, nascimento, endereco, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, uf, cep, tel_fixo_1, tel_fixo_2, tel_fixo_3, tel_cel_1, tel_cel_2, tel_cel_3)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

with open("Completo.csv", newline='') as f:
     cf = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
     for c in cf:
        mycursor.execute(sql, c)
```

Como você pode ver, `c` é uma sequência de valores que está sendo passada separadamente para o método `execute()` contendo os dados que serão inseridos. A query segue sem alterações, com os `%s` mesmo como estão.

Dessa forma, você também não precisa se preocupar com aspas uma vez que o mysql vai cuidar do tipo de dados automaticamente, e também não é preciso se preocupar com injeção de sql nas variáveis pois elas nunca serão parte da query.

Uma outra opção ainda mais rápida é usar o `executemany()`; Assim a operação é preparada uma vez só para todos os dados. Pode fazer muita diferença se forem muitos registros:

```
with open("Completo.csv", newline='') as f:
    cf = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    mycursor.executemany(sql, cf)
```

Comment: Legal, para reduzir a quantidade de 's' poderia ser realizado algo como `"""... (""" + "%s, " * 9 + "%s)"`, com `''.join([])` sintaticamente possibilita uma melhor leitura.

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on, upag, valor, prazo, banco, nascimento, endereco, numero, complemento, bairro' at line 1

Comment: Ele me retornou este erro seguindo o primeiro método

Comment: @LinhadeCódigo parece que você tem um espaço no nome de campo `sub on`... Então nesse campo é preciso usar o *backtick* ou "crase" (`) para o mysql reconhecer. Editei a resposta, veja se é isso

Comment: Deu certo! muito obrigado.